# java VLCJ tutorial java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, vlcj, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to use VLCJ, and got stuck on their [first tutorial](http://www.capricasoftware.co.uk/vlcj/tutorial1.php).

Here's my code:

```
package vlcj.tutorial1;

import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;

public class Tutorial1A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Ensure we're using the 32bit jdk.
        System.out.println("jdk version:  " + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model") + " bits.");

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/sdk/lib");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);
    }
}
```

Here's the output and exception I get:

```
jdk version:  32 bits.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libvlc': The specified module could not be found.

at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:169)
at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:242)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353)
at vlcj.tutorial1.Tutorial1A.main(Tutorial1A.java:17)
```

I made sure I'm using a 32 bit jdk and a 32 bit version of VLC.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code I have uses '{Install Path}/VideoLAN/VLC` (ie `C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC`, but I also look for `libvlc.dll` and `libvlcore.dll` within the that folder to be sure

Comment: @MadProgrammer that worked!  Thanks very much :)  If you want to chuck that comment in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `{Install Path}/VideoLAN/VLC` (ie `C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC`) instead.

I look for `libvlc.dll` and `libvlcore.dll` within that folder to be sure that the libraries are installed, but that's just me ;)

Comment: Just changed `C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/sdk/lib` to `C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC` and it worked :)  Thanks again @MadProgrammer!

Comment: Yeah, it took a bit of head to desk interactions when I was trying to get it to work to :P

Comment: @PetroSemeniuk I was just lucky enough to have my library code at hand ;)

Comment: somehow it said : %1 is not a valid Win32 application." what is that VLC ?

Comment: @gumuruh Hard to say, my guess is you've got the wrong version (x64 instead of x32)

Comment: omg! you're correct! somebody installed the x32 bit under my x64 machine lately.... 
i will remove it and install a new one with x64 bit correctly now :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to use double backward slash in path:

`"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\sdk\\lib"`

instead of:

`"C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/sdk/lib"`

Comment: I have working vlcj app working at home. I'll dig into sources tonight  and will be back.