# Vlcj jna unsatisfied link error unable to locate native libraries

Tags: java, jna, vlcj

I have already seen the links

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963171/java-vlcj-tutorial-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066731/cannot-fix-vlcj-load-library-libvlc)
3. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29408258/unable-to-load-libraries-libvlc)

These are my system specs

1. Windows 64bit
2. Java 11 64 bit
3. Vlc 32 bit
4. [vlcj 3.5.0 downloaded with maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/uk.co.caprica/vlcj/3.5.0)

This is my code

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),"C:Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),LibVlc.class);
```

And This Is My Error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libvlc': JNA native support (win32-amd64/libvlc.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Program Files\Java\Vlcj\jna-3.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\Vlcj\platform-3.5.2.jar;C:\Users\Home\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JDK Examples\Chat Application\Tests\build\classes)
```

Now i know you shoudn't be loading VLC 32 bit libraries using an 64 bit JRE and that's why i don't expect this program to work(or maybe it will i don't know) but the error message would have been diffrent something starting like IA32 or similar but that's not the case , as you can see despite adding the search path using NativeLibrary class the Native class seems to be searching for the dll's in the jar files & in my project path but not in the search path i have explictly mentioned so my Native can't even locate the dll files.

Help anyone?

Comment: How is your problem [different from this one](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/359)?

Comment: I tired with both 64 & 32 bit vlc but same error. Reinstalling both didn't fix the problem

Comment: Does your file path need to start `C:\\Program...`

Comment: And silly question but when you installed 64 bit did you remove the `(x86)` from the path?

Comment: Yes it does start with C://Program Files and yes i manually uninstalled 32 bit vlc with control panel and i also deleted Preferences & Caches before installing 64 bit vlc and vice versa with 32 vlc and then i gave up and installed both but no use

Comment: My path dosen't have to start with C:\\Program Files It can also just be C:/Program Files but both don't work removing (x86) didn't make a difference

Comment: Class `RuntimeUtil` is part of VLCJ library. Can you call a method of this class before you have loaded the library?

Comment: Yes I can it returns libvlc when I call getLibVlcLibraryName()

Comment: Error message looks identical to the issue I posted though, which still makes me think it's not a JNA problem, but some sort of system config/search path issue.

Comment: Well i also added VLC_PLUGIN_PATH as an system variable but it didn't help

Comment: This is not a valid path is it: "C:Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC", you are missing a backslash after the C:. And to answer another point, it will definitely not work if you mix 32bit and 64bit VLC and JVM.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo error i entered C:/Program Files(x86)/VideoLAN/VLC but it didn't work anyway i posted my fix in the answer below

Comment: I can't see in the code why "it didn't work". Were there more suppressed exceptions than the one listed, which indicated the other paths that it searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in 3 steps

1)Using Native discovery which was suggested from the link in the first comment because `NativeLibrary.addSearchPath` didn't do anything so i removed that line and replaced it with

```
new NativeDiscovery().discover();
```

2)Using vlc 64 bit

2)The "Main fix" was downgrading my **JDK from 11 to 1.8** for some reason  vlcj 3.5 and above won't work with my latest JDK and i can't understand it but it was this main change that allowed NativeDiscovery to work

Comment: I use vlcj with JDK 11 routinely just fine, so I very much doubt that's the real cause of your issue. IME this issue is a mismatch between JVM and VLC architectures (64-bit vs 32-bit).

Comment: I myself don't understand it but anything higher than JDK 11 wont work in my system so if you do have an explanation please do tell